# RelativeLayout.BELOW does not work correctly, android java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The following snippet of code places `test_above` and `test_below` at the top of the screen, not above and below the `test` element as needed

How can I fix the alignment in `addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, noteOut.getId());`
and `addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, noteOut.getId());` ?

```
    //Add the frequency display
    noteOut = new TextView(this);
    freqOut = new TextView(this);
    tuneOut = new TextView(this);
    noteOut.setText("test");
    freqOut.setText("test_below");
    tuneOut.setText("test_above");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams noteOutDetails = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    noteOutDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    noteOutDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    gameLayout.addView(noteOut, noteOutDetails);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tuneOutDetails = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    tuneOutDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    tuneOutDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, noteOut.getId());
    gameLayout.addView(tuneOut, tuneOutDetails);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams freqOutDetails = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    freqOutDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    freqOutDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, noteOut.getId());
    gameLayout.addView(freqOut, freqOutDetails);
```

Output of the emualator shown below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it was missing

```
    noteOut.setId(3);
```

However, this displays as an error in Android Studio, eventhough it compiles

`expected Resource of Type ID`